# Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent error using rCBA::fpgrowth

Tags: r, fpgrowth

I have the following dataset for which I want to generate association rules using FP growth

```
> head(order_pairs)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  product_A          product_B                       
  <chr>              <chr>                           
1 Organic Egg Whites Michigan Organic Kale           
2 Organic Egg Whites Garlic Powder                   
3 Organic Egg Whites Coconut Butter                  
4 Organic Egg Whites Natural Sweetener               
5 Organic Egg Whites Carrots                         
6 Organic Egg Whites Original Unflavored Gelatine Mix
```

Following the example on the documentation [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rCBA/versions/0.4.3/topics/fpgrowth) I performed the following steps before generating the rules.

```
train = sapply(orders_pairs,as.factor)
train = as.data.frame(train, check.names = FALSE)
transactions = as(train, 'transactions')
rules = rCBA::fpgrowth(transactions, support=0.01, confidence=0.01, maxLength=2, consequent="product_B", parallel=FALSE)
```

```
> head(train)
           product_A                        product_B
1 Organic Egg Whites            Michigan Organic Kale
2 Organic Egg Whites                    Garlic Powder
3 Organic Egg Whites                   Coconut Butter
4 Organic Egg Whites                Natural Sweetener
5 Organic Egg Whites                          Carrots
6 Organic Egg Whites Original Unflavored Gelatine Mix
```

A little reading led me to find that the error has something to do with the consequent parameter having a valid column name.
However *"product_B"* is a valid column name in my data

```
> colnames(orders_pairs)
[1] "product_A" "product_B"

> colnames(train)
[1] "product_A" "product_B"
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: @code-noob I ran into the same issue. Were you able to resolve it?